How to remove the graphics created by the Shadowcast widget
Using ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript 4.29, I'm working with the Shadowcast widget in a SceneView, and want to know how to disable the widget and remove the shadow layer that it creates.
I can disconnect the widget from the SceneView, and remove its UI panel using...
widget.view = null;
view.ui.remove(widget);

... but I can't figure out how to remove the shadows. Even worse, after disconnecting the widget from the view the shadows remain but are un-connected to the view, so they move independently:

See the demo at https://codepen.io/slead/pen/MWdWGMw which is based on the default Esri demo for the Shadowcast widget, with a new Remove button which performs the above steps - but note that the shadows remain after this.
Using widget.destroy() at least the shadows retain their correct position - but they still remain on the sceneView.
How can I remove the shadows from the view?

When I tried .destroy() method, shadows disappeared.

For me widget.destroy() method worked, it removed the widget UI and shadows. If you want just to hide the widget (to be used later), you can use .visible property:
buttonRemove.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  widget.visible = false;
});


Many thanks for the tip. The problem is that I was calling widget.destroy() after view.ui.remove(widget), which didn't work. Calling destroy first works, and visible=false is another great workaround
